# Radio Buttons and ListView - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

[image]I have a long list of radio buttons using `RadioListTile`. The problem is that the list is very long and overflows at the bottom of the page and therefore I need to find a way to scroll down. I've tried implementing `RadioListTile` with `ListView` but haven't been successful! Anyone knows how to fix this problem? Thanks!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const values = <String>[
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
    '10',
    '11',
    '12',
    '13',
    '14',
  ];
  String selectedValue = values.first;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Divider(color: Colors.white),
            Material(child: buildRadios()),
            Divider(color: Colors.white),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildRadios() => Column(
        children: values.map(
          (value) {
            return RadioListTile<String>(
              value: value,
              groupValue: selectedValue,
              title: Text(value),
              onChanged: (value) => setState(() => this.selectedValue = value!),
            );
          },
        ).toList(),
      );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code, and Wrap your [**`Column`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) inside [**`SingleChildScrollView`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html)

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Divider(color: Colors.white),
          Material(child: buildRadios()),
          Divider(color: Colors.white),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Result Screen -> [image: immage]

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your RadioListTile within Scrollbar Widget.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately!

Comment: I could be wrong, can you try to wrap within ListView widget instead of Column

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `buildRadios(`) with `Expanded` Widget

Comment: This looks like it might be a useful contribution, just consider expanding the answer with a concrete example, explanation and links to documentation.